# didn't get deselected on pagination - Datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I have a datatable with select all option . My datatable contains files and links . I need to select only rows contains files . selected count is showing there . My code is below

```
var mydata = $('#document-table').DataTable({
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "info": false,
        "pageLength": 20,
        "searching": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "select": {
            'style':    'multi',
            'selector': 'tr:not(.no-select)'
        },
        "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ){
            if(data[2] == ''){
               $('td:eq(0)', row).removeClass('select-checkbox');
               $(row).addClass('no-select');
            }
            else {
                $(row).removeClass('no-select');
             }
        },
        "columnDefs": [
                {
                'targets': 0,
                'checkboxes': {
                   'selectRow': true
                },
                'render': function(){
                   return '';
                }
             },
        ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    });

    mydata.on("click", "th.select-checkbox", function() {
        if ($("th.select-checkbox").hasClass("selected")) {
            mydata.rows().deselect();
            $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            mydata.rows().select();
            $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
        }
    }).on("select deselect", function() {
        var count = mydata.rows({
                selected: true
            }).count();
        if (count !== mydata.rows().count()) {
            $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
        }
        mydata.rows('tr.no-select').deselect();
    });
```

I need to deselect every row with class '.no-select' when I clicking on select all button. My code is working for first page . But in the other pages all rows are selected . How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change callback option,

from

> "rowCallback"

into this

> "createdRow"

From documentation, `rowCallback` is triggered before the row node is rendered into the document and `createdRow` is triggered after the row node is inserted into the DOM.

Link: [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) , [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow)

Then using $() api to perform Jquery selection action on full table inside select-all checkbox on click event.

> The selector given to the $() method will be run on all of the tr
>   elements in the table, and their descendent elements, with the found
>   elements being returned as a jQuery object.

link: [$()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24())

You can filter the selector like this

`tr:not(.no-select)`

into this

```
table
     .DataTable()
     .$('tr:not(.no-select)')
     .toggleClass("selected",this.checked);
```

Not so perfect, see sample based on your requirement below.

> Example of empty 2nd column is on page 1 and 4

```js
var mydata = $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "info": false,
        "searching": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "createdRow": function( row, data, index ){
            if(data[2] == ''){
               $('td:eq(0)', row).removeClass('select-checkbox');
               $(row).addClass('no-select');
            }
            else {
                $(row).removeClass('no-select');
             }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'tr:not(.no-select)'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} )

mydata.on("click", "th.select-checkbox input", function() {

var table = $(this).closest('table');

//update botton checkbox
table.find('th.select-checkbox input').prop('checked', this.checked);

//update all data across all pages
  table
    .DataTable()
    .$('tr:not(.no-select)')
    .toggleClass("selected",this.checked);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="select-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="select-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: rows from second page didnt get selected